# How to use search plugin in Joomla component?

Tags: search, plugins, joomla, triggers, components

I am writing a new component which require content search functionality.

I would like to make use of the system search plugin to do the job.

I have done some google searching, and I found that I can trigger the search event in component, but I failed to implement that...

Can anyone help?

I am running Joomla 2.5

Comment: If you failed to implement it, can you show the code you were using to try and do so?

Comment: I end up using the below code and it done the job successfully.

Comment: `$dispatcher =& JDispatcher::getInstance();
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('search');
$results = $dispatcher->trigger('onContentSearch', array($_POST['q']));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using this code and it works

`$dispatcher =& JDispatcher::getInstance();
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('search');
$results = $dispatcher->trigger('onContentSearch', array($_POST['q']));`